# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when modifying list

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm trying to delete some files in my database using App Engine and objectify. This the piece of code where I have the exception:

```
for(SottoCategoria sc: lsc){
      List<Key<Dispensa>> ld2=sc.getDispense();
      if(ld2!=null){
         for(Key<Dispensa> kd : ld2){ // <---- Exception!!
            if(kd.equals(k)){
                sc.removeDispensa(k);
                ofy().save().entity(sc).now();
                                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method that remove from the list:

```
public void removeDispensa(Key<Dispensa> k ){
    Iterator<Key<Dispensa>> kIter = dispense.iterator();
    while(kIter.hasNext()) {
        Key<Dispensa> kk = kIter.next();
        System.out.println(kk.equals(k));
        if(kk.equals(k)){
            kIter.remove();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

How can I resolve it? Thanks!

Edit:

I resolved inserting a simple break in the loop, because in Sottocategoria can be only one dispensa that i want to remove!

Comment: In `for(Key<Dispensa> kd : ld2){`, in the first code, why do you need that loop there?

Comment: because i have subcategories with many items of Dispensa. So if i need to remove an item Dispensa, i have to loop for every subcategory every list of items Dispensa.

Comment: I thought in both the cases the looping was over the same list.

Comment: Nono.. But in other projects i think tu use iterators for this type of problems. am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConcurrentModificationException occurs because you are try to delete a part of your list, while you are iterating through it. Try it with a for loop with index or creat a iterator.

example for-loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<dispense.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(dispense.get(i).equals(k));
        if(dispense.get(i).equals(k)){
            dispense.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

example iterator:

```
    Iterator<Key<Dispensa>> It = dispense.iterator();
    while(It.hasNext()) {
        Key<Dispensa> kk = It.next();
        System.out.println(kk.equals(k));
        if(kk.equals(k)){
            dispense.remove(kk);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your example of the loop gave me the idea to resolve the problem!! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are more suited to this use case.

Here is an example:

```
public void removeDispensa(Key<Dispensa> k ){
    Iterator<Dispensa> kIter = k.iterator();
    while(kIter.hasNext()) {
        Dispensa kk = kIter.next();
        System.out.println(kk.equals(k));
        if(kk.equals(k)){
            kIter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your remove() is empty.

Comment: That is correct, there is no parameter to pass in. It instructs the Iterator to remove its current item.

Comment: Nope. It removes from the list which you are iterating over. I suggest you read up on Iterators :)
And by the way, the answer which you wrote will not compile, because .remove() takes no parameters.

Comment: i dont have to read the oracle docs. the .remove() function in the iterator class dont take parameters, but look whats in front of my remove(kk); I delete kk from the dispense list ;) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html this remove takes parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it with `List.iterator()` to avoid this exception.

**ConcurrentModificationException** - This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible. This will not happen when you go for an iterator.Using an Iterator to iterate through a Collection is the safest and fastest way to traverse through a Collection

Answer (score 1):

You can´t modify the list you are iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is because you are trying to modify the same array that you are reading, so to avoid the problem yo must replicate your array and iterate the duplicate array and doing the operations in the good one.

Tell me if you need some help with the code

Comment: Rafa: please avoid approving terrible edits to your answer. A user, Finga officiel, tried to insert his own question within your answer, and for some reason, you approved it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the info! Yes, I approved by error... sorry!