# Any idea what could be causing this java.util.concurrentModificationException from unmanaged code in Xamarin.Forms on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, telerik

I keep getting the following exception randomly from the Android project in my Xamarin.Forms application.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next (ArrayList.java:860)
  at com.telerik.widget.primitives.panels.RadScrollView.notifyLaidOutListeners (RadScrollView.java:153)
  at com.telerik.widget.primitives.panels.RadScrollView.onLayout (RadScrollView.java:2092)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ViewRenderer_2.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ViewRenderer_2.onLayout (ViewRenderer_2.java:47)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc64ee486da937c010f4.FrameRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc64ee486da937c010f4.FrameRenderer.onLayout (FrameRenderer.java:47)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewContainer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewContainer.onLayout (ScrollViewContainer.java:46)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onLayout (NestedScrollView.java:1854)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewRenderer.onLayout (ScrollViewRenderer.java:91)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onLayout (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PageRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PageRenderer.onLayout (PageRenderer.java:72)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.NavigationPageRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.NavigationPageRenderer.onLayout (NavigationPageRenderer.java:65)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout (FormsViewGroup.java:37)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.MasterDetailContainer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.MasterDetailContainer.onLayout (MasterDetailContainer.java:46)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1231)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.MasterDetailPageRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.MasterDetailPageRenderer.onLayout (MasterDetailPageRenderer.java:68)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.onLayout (PlatformRenderer.java:55)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1103)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:1225)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:4260)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1010)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:809)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:744)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:995)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8538)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

It seems to be happening randomly and I am just hoping that someone has faced the same issue and has an idea on what to do? I am unable to debug as it comes from code that is unmanaged. Any thoughts on what could be causing this and any potential solutions would be much apppreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Based from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/20402878/4778712 did you do like that?

Comment: This exception does not come from my code. It seems to be coming from unmanaged code. I dont have any such for loop in my code.

Comment: What XF version did you use?

Comment: I use Xamarin forms 5.0.0.2196

Comment: Try adding this lib `Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView`

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging it turns out it was related to having a **Horizontally scrollable control (Telerik DataGrid)** inside a **vertically scrollable Layout (Scrollview)** and then Trying to use **`ScrollToAsync()`** on Android when the an entry in the DataGrid is focused.

To fix this, in my **`OnAppearing()`** override I checked that the **`Device.RuntimePlatform`** is Android and checked if the **DataGrid Control** should be visible by using the **`IsVisible`** Binding property from my view model and then removed it. This control is inside a grid so I was able to do this using the **`x:Names`** of the controls and calling **`.Children.Remove()`**.

And then used **Device.RuntimePlatform** to check if the device is Android and if it the **ScrollToAsync()** is not called.

so the code looked something like:

```
var vm = BindingContext as MyViewModelName;
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android && !vm.DataGridIsVisible){
    MyGridControl.Children.Remove(MyDataGridControl);
}
```

Note that `MyGridControl` and `MyDataGridControl` here are the `X:Name` properties of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only provide error information, from the error information, this error generally appears in the iteration of **ArrayList**.

The main reason is that the values of `modCount` and `expectedModCount` are inconsistent due to calling list.remove() method.

If you use an iterator This error can be avoided by calling `Iterator.remove()` directly.

If you just call the API without other operations, it should be a similar problem with the internal interface.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is coming from unmanaged code so I don't have much control there. That being said, after much debugging it turns out it was related to having a **Horizontally scrollable control (Telerik DataGrid)** inside a vertically scrollable Layout (scrollview). So in my OnAppearing override I just checked for Android platform and removed this control if the isVisibleProperty (the property is was bound to in my view model) was supposed to be set to false. This solved the problem for me